# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to convert data to an object

Tags: python, selenium

I originally wanted to get rid of the cookies bar, which I succeeded in but the "load more" but then proceeded to get the error: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: Element  is not clickable at point (483,668) because another element  obscures it.

So, I tried to close that as well but got the new error:
    selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to convert 
    data to an object.

I'm not sure what to do with this new error.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import time

url = "https://www.standardmedia.co.ke/politics#"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
page_num = 0

popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 
15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "mc- 
closeModal")))
popup.click()
page_num += 1

#close pop-up
dismiss = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.cc-dismiss')
dismiss.click()

#click load more until the end is reached
while driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.catloadmore'):
    cookies_div = driver.find_element_by_id('cookieconsent:desc')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display="none";', 
    cookies_div)
    div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('cc-window cc-banner cc- 
    type-info cc-theme-block cc-bottom cc-color-override-236176093  cc- 
    invisible')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display="none";', div)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 
    15).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 
    ".catloadmore"))).click()

driver.quit()

 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "\\Mac\Home\Desktop\Global Health Job\the_standard_scraping.py", 
 line 42, in <module>
     nav_div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('cc-window cc-banner cc- 
 type-info cc-theme-block cc-bottom cc-color-override-236176093  cc- 
 invisible')
   File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
 packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in 
 find_element_by_class_name
     return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
   File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
 packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in 
  find_element
     'value': value})['value']
   File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
 packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
   File "C:\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site- 
 packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in 
 check_response
     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Failed to 
 convert data to an object
```

Comment: Try changing `nav_div = driver.find_element_by_class_name('cc-window cc-banner cc- 
 type-info cc-theme-block cc-bottom cc-color-override-236176093  cc- 
 invisible')` to `nav_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class='cc-window cc-banner cc- 
 type-info cc-theme-block cc-bottom cc-color-override-236176093  cc- 
 invisible'])`

Comment: I got a syntax error for that exact change but got the same "Failed to convert data to an object" error when I used `nav_div = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//cc-window//cc-banner//cc-type-info//cc-theme-block//cc-bottom//cc-color-override-236176093//cc-invisible')`

Comment: Try this `nav_div = driver.find_element_by_css("div[class='cc-window cc-banner cc-type-info cc-theme-block cc-bottom cc-color-override-236176093 ']")`.

Comment: I am able to hide the element successfully using the css in the browser console.

Comment: have you got a solution?

Comment: @epair are you still searching for an answer? For me it's not clear what you goal is with this webpage

Comment: @Frank No, I decided to abandon using selenium and opted for using just BeautifulSoup instead.

Comment: Thanks, good to know.